# How to insert txt file to sklearn using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying load huge dataset into sklearn system via a txt file. Or is there a easy method to upload it

Comment: This is far too broad/vague.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem do you have to read it?
As a general suggestion you can read it with chunks:

```
chunksize = 10000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    # do whatever you suppose to
```

Specify the chunksize parameter properly to your PC configuration.
You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) question for more options.